# React index.html page separation using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using react's **create-react-app** for my new application.
I am really getting confused to separate index.html page for client side and admin panel.
I have different functional flows and css files for both side.
So index.html file should be loaded based on router navigation.

Example:

http://example.com => should load client/index.html

http://example.com/admin => should load admin/index.html

Note: i have tried webpack's multiple entries method and **webpack html plugin**. But it only separates bundle files not html(while navigate).

Please help me out.

Comment: You admin panel is still on the client-side, just that it is restricted to a different kind of users. You should have one `index.html`, and load a different component into it using a router, like React Router.

Comment: ok but in component, variables must be declared to use those scripts. Since those scripts are jquery dependent, we cannot overwrite any variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after using the below code to include the external scripts, I don't really want any additional html pages.

var $script = require("scriptjs")

$script("/myscript.js")

Answer (score 0):

webpack just a module bundler, It doesn't control which page show, This should be done by router.

if it's single page, you can use [react-router](https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router)

if it's multi page, you can use [express route](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)